# Giving labels in pandas data frame

Tags: python, pandas, data-science

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g9V1S.png)

Hi, in the above picture I have a column named taxable income .
I want to add one more column next to it such that the income less than equal to 30000 is labelled as risky and income more than 30000 is labelled as good.

Answer (score 0):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"Taxable.Income" : [15000 + random.randint(0,1)*30000 for i in range(500)]}) # creating a sample data frame
```

data frame looks like this

[image]

```
df['label'] = df["Taxable.Income"].apply(lambda x : "good" if x >30000 else " risky")
df
```

output:

[image]